# How can I make multi-screen settings persist after reboot?

Tags: multiple-monitors, reboot, settings, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and went through loads of settings. Among them, I followed the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html

The screens do what I want... until I reboot. Then the displays settings are back at their defaults. How/where can I save my settings so that a restart with the same monitors will reload the settings for them?

Notes:
1) This was not a problem in 16.10 with Gnome desktop on same machine with same monitors. It is new (for me) only since installing 18.04

2) Machine is Acer laptop with Intel i5 CPU and its on-board HD620 graphics. The Intel graphics driver is installed, but I haven't yet figured out how to see if it's the driver in use. Monitors are built-in + attached flat-screen (attached throughout power-up, boot and login).

PS: If my question is a duplicate, *please* point to the earlier answer (because I've searched and couldn't find it myself).

PPS: It's now September, and I'm growing accustomed to the default (two screens). Other display settings persist, but the mirroring never did.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where you can check which graphics driver is in use: Activities -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I was looking for something that would help boot my System 76 laptop (Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4), with Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) in "Join Displays" mode, as opposed to "Mirror".

What I discovered was `arandr`.  It's a very plain version of "Settings > Devices > Displays", which displayed the settings I had already defined, but weren't working as expected.  It let me save a file with those settings to `~/.screenlayout` as an `.sh` file.  I then added it to my `~/.bashrc` (after testing what it would do.)

After rebooting, it worked like a charm and didn't require any of the heavy tinkering almost three hours of research was suggesting I'd do (including one that forced me to use recovery mode to uninstall the packages so my laptop would boot properly.)

I saved the file that it generated as `~/.screenlayout/join.sh`, since they already seemed to have placed `mirror.sh` in the same directory (which was a wonderful clue as to how I should name it.)

**join.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-1 --off --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 280x1440 --rotate normal --output HDMI-2 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

**mirror.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-1 --off --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

The file it generated also happened to be a great reference on how I can use `xrandr` in the future.

Hopefully this will save someone a few hours of sleep. ;)